# Como criar o campo ANEXO em um formulário no xamarin forms?

Tags: input, xamarin-forms

Eu tenho um formulário sendo desenvolvido em uma aplicação mobile, um dos campos terá que capturar um anexo. Eu sei como fazer em html usando o `input`, portanto qual seria o atributo para fazer isso usando o xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Xamarin.Forms ainda não provê no seu pacote um componente para seleção de arquivo.

No entanto, há algumas implementações (de código aberto inclusive) nesse sentido, já que é uma necessidade muito comum nos aplicativos.

Aqui tem duas opções:

- [Xam.Plugin.FilePicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.FilePicker) <- Mais usado
- [pt.Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pt.Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker/1.3.2)

Lembrando que esse tipo de componente geralmente não oferece uma interface visual, então seu acionamento deve ser imperativo. Por exemplo, na sua View você coloca um botão e no evento de click (ou no command da viewModel) você aciona a ação disponibilizada pelo componente, como selecionar, salvar ou abrir um arquivo.

Ex.:

```
ICommand command = new Command(async () => 
{
    var fileData = await filePicker.Current.PickFile();
    // A partir daqui você usa o fileData como precisar
});
```

Comment: Entendi, eu fiz um pouco diferente portanto ta dando erro no ExceptionHandler, sabe me dizer porque??
`public async void anexarArquivo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.ShowException(ex.Message);
            }
        }`

Comment: @WPfan qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Que ele não existe no contexto atual!

Comment: Esse `ExceptionHandler` parece uma classe própria ou você precisa instanciá-la ou precisa incluir a referencia do namespace dela. Sugiro você colocar um breakpoint no catch e verificar qual a mensagem de erro original